# Azure - devops : run ps1 file within Inline script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

how can I call a ps1 file from AzureDevops powershell Iniline script ? I am getting:
The term 'run.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I make sure that i am on the same Location as the file using Set-Location first.

Comment: Remove the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Just like as calling the **`.ps1`** script file on your local PowerShell, on the PowerShell task inline script, you can call your **`.ps1`** script file as "**`.\run.ps1`**".

Below is an example as reference.

- Store the **`.ps1`** script file in the source git repository.
  [image]
- YAML

  ```yaml
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Test PowerShell script'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          Write-Host "This is output from the inline script."
          .\ps-script.ps1
  ```
- Result
  [image]